# How executable binaries works after unmounting root file system in single user mode?

Tags: linux, redhat

My root filesystem got corrupted and to fix this I went in to single user mode and ran the fsck on the unmounted root filesystem.My question is how /sbin/fsck command works after unmounting the root file system and where its located?

OS: Redhat Linux

Comment: In that case you've mounted the root file system in read-only mode, which keeps the binaries available, but allows you to run a writable fsck on the partition.

Comment: I didn't mounted the partition on ro mode. there are the sequence of commands I have ran to fix the issue.umount -f / ; fsck /dev/sda1; mount -a

Answer (score 1):

In the linux source, even if you ask to umount the root file system, it doesn't actually happen - the [source makes this clear](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/namespace.c#L1508) with a comment and the tricksy code:

```
if (mnt == current->fs->root.mnt && !(flags & MNT_DETACH)) {
    /*
     * Special case for "unmounting" root ...
     * we just try to remount it readonly.
     */
    down_write(&sb->s_umount);
    if (!(sb->s_flags & MS_RDONLY))
        retval = do_remount_sb(sb, MS_RDONLY, NULL, 0);
    up_write(&sb->s_umount);
    return retval;
}
```

This is why binaries on the root file system are still present; they've not actually gone away.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it is the one that lives in ramdisk, which is loaded by bootloader and resided in sdram and work as first stage root. try the command:
mount
without any parameters, it will tell you exactly root which system is currently using.